# Not retrieving any information from model using Ember.js using query() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, routes, ember-data

I'm trying to learn Ember.js by building a web application using the framework for the front end and node.js for the backend as well as mongoDB as a database.

I am using/attempting to use the url to feed in a parameter id and then query on that id.

I am having trouble grabbing the information from my model. My query works fine when I am using findAll(). However, when I switch to  find() or query() I can't retrieve any results.

All the documentation I have looked at use different syntax that I have tried but none have worked.

I would greatly appreciate any hint or input. Thank you.

app/router.js

```
    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('stock', { path: '/:stock_id' });
    });
```

app/routes/stock.js

```
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
       model: function(params) {
         this.store.query('stock', {filter:{id : params.stock_id}}).then(function(stock){return stock.get('firstObject')});
       }
    });
```

app/models/stock.js

```
    export default DS.Model.extend({
       Symbol: DS.attr('string'),
       Name: DS.attr('string'),
       LastSale: DS.attr('string'),
       MarketCap: DS.attr('string'),
       IPOyear: DS.attr('string'),
       Industry: DS.attr('string')
    });
```

app/serializers/stock.js

```
    export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
       primaryKey: '_id',
       serializeId: function(id) {
          return id.toString();
       }
    });
```

app/templates/stock.hbs

```
   {{#each model as |item|}}
   <h3>{{item.Name}}</h3>
   {{/each}}
```

my nodejs server

```
     app.get('/api/stocks/:id', function(req, res){
        StockModel.findOne({'_id': req.params.id},function(err,docs){
           console.log(docs.symbol);
           if(err){
              res.send({error:err});
           }
           else{
             res.send({stock:docs});
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: model hook should return the result

Comment: Thank you for the response, from my understanding am I not already doing that within my app/routes/stock.js route above?

Comment: You missed a `return` in `model()`!

Answer (score 1):

Model hook should return the result, only then this will be set in `model` in corresponding controller through setupController method hook.

```
model: function(params) {
         return this.store.query('stock', {filter:{id : params.stock_id}}).then(function(stock){return stock.get('firstObject')});
       }
```

---

Update:
Your model field name should be camelCased

```
// app/models/stock.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
symbol: DS.attr('string'),
name: DS.attr('string'),
lastSale: DS.attr('string'),
marketCap: DS.attr('string'),
iPOyear: DS.attr('string'),
industry: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and ensure, your backend is accepting the `filter` and returning the required result in the below format,

```
"stocks": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "symbol": "foo",
    "name": "foo",
    "lastSale": "foo",
    "marketCap": "foo",
    "iPOyear": "foo",
    "industry": "foo" 
}]
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo. I am still not able to retrieve the data from the model. I can only retrieve data when I use findAll() but that retrieves all of the elements from the database and I only want to retrieve the one specific element using the id passed from the url parameters.

Comment: Just ensure query is returning proper valid response.

Comment: I printed out the result to the console and get a bunch of data no where near what I want. I did notice that as soon as enter the url (i.e localhost/id) I automatically call my node.js server and it retrieves the correct information. I just can't seem to grab that within the model hook.

Comment: I was able to finally get the internal model to retrieve the data as it is from the database using findRecord() instead of query for some reason. However, I still can't display that information on any page.

Comment: I am not aware of the node stuff. Dont forget to return the result in model hook, and if you override setupController hook, then dont forget to call the `this._super(...arguments)`.

Comment: RESTAPI format model name will be in plural `stocks`, in your node code its `stock`..

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the query from the model. Update your `app/routes/stock.js` to look like

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store
      .query('stock', {
        filter: {
          id: params.stock_id
        }
      })
      .then(stock => stock.get('firstObject'))
  }
})
```

Comment: FYI: `.then(stock => stock.get('firstObject'))` and `.then(function(stock){return stock.get('firstObject')})` both are same. but its good you are using ES6 feature but that does not play major role in solving the problem.

Comment: Just added the `return`. Rest is all clean up.